# Order of $U_{27}$, 2 Answers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

In my book I saw:

$$U_{27} = \{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26\}.$$

I know that order of group is the number of elements inside that group, so we get an order of $19$, but on the other hand my book claims it's $18$ since:

$$\phi(27) = 3^3-3^2=18.$$

I'm confused, why is that?

Comment: $24$ is not a unit mod $27$

Comment: Are you sure 24 belongs in that group?

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: In your post, $2^2$ is perhaps a typo that should be $3^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\gcd(24,27)=3$, we have $24\notin U_{27}$. The rest is fine.